# HAML vs Zen Coding

Tags: html, haml

I read about both [HAML](http://designshack.net/articles/html/save-loads-of-time-by-writing-your-html-with-haml/) vs [Zen Coding](http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/). Both can save time in typing HTML.

Which would be good to use and why?

Comment: This is a subjective question, not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Weird this was downvoted. Good question. I prefer zencoding as well.

Answer (score 10):

One can actually use [Zen Coding](http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/) to produce HAML.

Example:

```
#main.with-shadow>h1.title+h2.subtitle+p
```

Will produce, by default:

```
<div id="main" class="with-shadow">
    <h1 class="title"></h1>
    <h2 class="subtitle"></h2>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

If you would like that statement to expand to HAML, append "|haml" to your abbreviation:

```
#main.with-shadow>h1.title+h2.subtitle+p|haml
```

That should give you the following:

```
#main.with-shadow
    %h1.title
    %h2.subtitle
    %p
```

Read [here](http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/wiki/Filters) to learn more about filters for the Zen Coding expansions.

Answer (score 2):

HAML is kind of mini markup language whereas Zen Coding is collection of plugins (not markup language) made for various editors.

You can use either of them. I personally use Zen Coding though.

[Quote:](http://designshack.net/articles/html/save-loads-of-time-by-writing-your-html-with-haml/)

> At its core, Haml is a **lightweight markup language**.

--

> Zen Coding is an **editor plugin** for high-speed HTML, XML, XSL (or any
>   other structured code format) coding and editing. The core of this
>   plugin is a powerful abbreviation engine which allows you to expand
>   expressions—similar to CSS selectors—into HTML code.

Comment: OK to me it seems like both are option to save time on HTML writing.

Comment: @JitendraVyas: Yes you got it right :)

Comment: I feel that HAML will good for maintainability compare to Zen coding. Not sure though which approach is best.

Comment: @JitendraVyas: I personally use Zen Coding or other "Text Expanders" (you can search that on google). You might want to compare both and come up with a decision which one you use :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use both actually at the same time :) that's fast :)